# Should this question be transfered to pm.se?

Tags: discussion, questions

Should [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/231436/assigning-resources-to-ms-project-2007) be transfered to pm.se?

It is a problem with ms-project tool, but it also a problem about managing resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question, but no.  Although this question mentions managing resources, it not **about** managing resources.  It asks a very specific question about the relationship between resource groups and individual resource definitions *in MS Project 2007* - that makes it totally an SU question.

So now you can go back and answer that question there ;-)

Answer (score 1):

From the [Super User FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq):

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about …
>
> > computer hardware
> > computer software

From the [Project Management SE FAQ](https://pm.stackexchange.com/faq):

> Project Management - Stack Exchange is for project managers: development methods, documentation, personnel and resource management, time-tracking, estimation methods, success definitions, etc.

While Super User mentions `software`, Project Management SE does not mention software at all.  In addition, it's up to the Super User community to decide what belongs on their site.  If they feel it should be moved, then they'll vote to close it as `off topic, belongs on ____ SE site.`